# Analytical continuation and contour rotation

Tags: complex-analysis

I am rather desperate to understand how analytical continuation by contour rotation works.
An example I am particularly interested is the function$$f(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e ^{-az^2 - z} \mathrm{d}z$$.
The integral converges for $a>0$, while it diverges for $a<0$.  In order to find the analytical continuation of the function $f(a)$ for negative, real $a$, I though I could solve the integral for $a >0$ and insert a negative $a$ value in the ensuing Expression, exploting the fact the latter is still valid for begative $a$ values.

Instead, on many references in the physics literature I see references to "analytical continuation by contour rotation". Often the knowledge of the procedure is given for granted, as it is probably obvious, yet it defies my understanding. One example is detailed in http://stp.clarku.edu/kleinnotes/chapter3.pdf, page 10, after equation (3.31).
the method is based on evaluating the integral in Region of the complex plane such that the real part of the term $az^2$ is positive.

By setting $z=\rho e^{i\phi}$ and $a = e^{i \theta}$, one verifies that the requirement that the real part of $az^2$ is positive is translated to the condition $cos(\phi + 2\theta) > 0$. This I understand. The argument proceeds by considering a contour formed by 1) an interval [0 c] 2) a circular contour covering a sufficiently small angle 3) a line from the end of the circular arch to the origin (please see Fig. 3.4 on the above mentioned reference).

The integral over the cicrcular arch goes to Zero as $c$ goes to infinity, so using Cauchy Theorem one concludes that the integral over the contour Portion 1) is equal to the negative of the integral over the contour Portion 3). Iterating the argument, one can continue the process until $\Theta = \pi$. this should constitute the analytical continutamion, as $\Theta = \pi$ is related to a negative value of $a$.

My question is: is this approach not simply equal to changing the Integration Limits of the initial integral, from $\int _0 ^{\infty}$ to $ \int _{-\infty} ^0$? If that is so, where are the contours indicated in Fig 3.5 coming from?
 Also, the initial integral is not to be performed over a contour but over a line. Why then in the mentioend reference it is stated the initial integral is equal to the integral iver the contours of Fig. 3.5? The latter have a sense for a Steepest descent calculation, but the original Problem was to calculate the integral over the real line only, not a contour.

I apologise for referencing a source in such a way ist consultation is probably necessary to understand my question, but I still believe it is more efficient doing so rather that the re-writing all the Explanation.

I would be really grateful for your help this is is really puzzling me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{H}_+$ and $\mathbb{H}_\text{R}$ denote the upper and right half plane, respectively. 
Also we define
\begin{align}
\Gamma_1&=\{z:z=te^{-i\pi/4}, 0\le t<\infty\}\quad(\text{rotation of the positive real axis}),\\
\Gamma_{1,R}&=\{z:z=te^{-i\pi/4}, 0\le t\le R\},\\ 
C_{1,R}&=\{z: z=Re^{-i\theta} , 0\le \theta \le \pi/4\} \quad (\text{with clockwise direction}).
\end{align}

For $a\in \mathbb{H}_\text{R}$
$$f(a)=\int_0^\infty e^{-az^2-z}dz$$
is well defined (the integral converges) and analytic in $\mathbb{H}_\text{R}$. Also we define $$
f_1(a)=\int_{\Gamma_1} e^{-az^2-z}dz\quad $$
for $a\in \mathbb{H}_+$.
Since the integral in RHS converges, $f_1(a)$ is analytic in $\mathbb{H}_+$.

We prove $$
f(a)=f_1(a)\quad (a\in \mathbb{H}_+\cap\mathbb{H}_\text{R}).$$
By Cauchy's theorem $$
\int_0^R  e^{-az^2-z}dz+\int_{C_{1,R}}  e^{-az^2-z}dz-\int_{\Gamma_{1,R}}e^{-az^2-z}dz=0.$$
Letting $R\to \infty$ we have$$
\int_0^\infty  e^{-az^2-z}dz=\int_{\Gamma_1}e^{-az^2-z}dz,$$
since $\int_{C_{1,R}}  e^{-az^2-z}dz\to 0\,(R\to \infty).$ This follows from the inequality
$$|e^{-az^2-z}|\le e^{-\operatorname{Re} az^2}\cdot e^{-\operatorname{Re}z}\le e^{-R\cos \theta }\le e^{-R/\sqrt{2}}
$$
for $a\in \mathbb{H}_+\cap\mathbb{H}_\text{R}$ and $z\in C_{1,R}.$
Therefore $f_1(a)$ is an analytic continuation of $f(a)$ to $\mathbb{H}_+.$

Let $\mathbb{H}_\text{L}$ denote the left half plane. Define
\begin{align}
\Gamma_2&=\{z:z=-it, 0\le t<\infty\},\\
f_2(a)&=\int_{\Gamma_2} e^{-az^2-z}dz\quad (a\in \mathbb{H}_\text{L})\\
&=-i\int_0^\infty e^{at^2+it}dt.
\end{align}

Again $f_2(a)$ is well defined in $\mathbb{H}_\text{L}$ and analytic there. By the same method as above we can prove that $$
f_1(a)=f_2(a)\quad (a\in \mathbb{H}_+\cap\mathbb{H}_\text{L}).$$
Therefore $f_2(a)$ is an analytic continuation of $f_1(a)$ to $\mathbb{H}_\text{L}$, so an analytic continuation of $f(a).$

Conclusion: By analytic continuation described above
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-az^2-z}dz\quad(a>0) \longrightarrow -i\int_0^\infty e^{az^2+iz}dz\quad(a<0)
$$